# Import filtered access query to power pivot /power query

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerpivot, powerquery

I have made a query in my Access database, where I have filters on some of the columns. When I try to import the query to Excel via PowerQuery or directly in PowerPivot, it ignores my "Not Like "*txtfilter*", but other text filters (= "text") are working fine.

The resulting datatable with the "Not Like"-filter has 14696 rows, but the imported table is without this filter, and has 15311 rows.

I would prefer to do the filtering in the database, to keep the number of rows in Excel limited. Why is this happening, and is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a Filter Step to the Power Query.  The easiest way is using the Filter button just to the right of each column header - e.g. Text Filters / Does Not Contain: txtfilter.

Comment: I will probably go with this solution, althoug it still bugs me that I cant import the view as is from Access. I need the data in different workbooks, so this means I will have to apply the filter for every woorkbook, instead of doing it once in the database.